# jQuery - buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an problem, I wrote an jQuery script

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api/template",
    processData: true,
    dataType: 'text',
    cache: false,
    success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
        template = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        if (template.templateCur == 1) {
            $("button[id='T1']").css("color", "red");
        } else {
            $("button[id='T1']").css("color", "black");
        }
        if (template.templateCur == 2) {
            $("button[id='T2']").css("color", "red");
        } else {
            $("button[id='T2']").css("color", "black");
        }
        if (template.templateCur == 3) {
            $("button[id='T3']").css("color", "red");
        } else {
            $("button[id='T3']").css("color", "black");
        }
    }
});
```

I have 3 buttons, if you load the website, script will load, and show you which template on a device is active - JSON says it.

So I have 3 different buttons. The script first checks through the JSON which of the three templates on my device is active and marks the button in red color. When I press another button, the device will change my template, but the button is not marked in red. That's the problem, how can I make it so that the script always executes new when I will click the buttons. Next I will have more buttons and I dont want that the code will be to long.

Comment: Why would you set the dataType to text when you're getting JSON? Also, it's not at all clear what it is you're asking for here ?

Comment: Can you add some more detail to what you're expecting to happen. The point of your question is not clear.

Comment: So I have 3 different buttons. The script first checks through the JSON which of the three templates on my device is active and marks the button in red color. When I press another button, the device will change my template, but the button is not marked in red. That's the problem, how can I make it so that the script always executes new when I will click the buttons.

Next I will have more buttons and I dont want that the code will be to long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<button class="myButton" id="T1">My Button</button>
<button class="myButton" id="T2">My Button</button>
<button class="myButton" id="T3">My Button</button>
```

**JS**

```
$('.myButton').on('click', function () { //Event Handler for your button
    myRequest(); //Call the request function
});

function myRequest() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/template",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (template) {
            $('.myButton').css("color", "black"); //Reset all buttons with class "myButton"
            $("#T" + template.templateCur).css("color", "red"); //Set color for active Template-Button
        }
    });
}


(function(){
    myRequest();
})();
```